# How do I get the feed of a public Facebook page in an iOS app without prompting the user for Facebook permissions?

Tags: ios, facebook, access-token, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to get the feed of a public Facebook page using the Graph API and I can't figure out how to do so without prompting the user for permissions.

The following code works, but prompts the user for permissions:

```
- (void)doFacebookAuthCompletion:(void (^)(ACAccount* account))completion
{
    ACAccountStore* accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType* accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    NSDictionary* fbOptions = @{
                                ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"<app-id-key>",
                                ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[ @"email" ]
                                };

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType
                                          options:fbOptions
                                       completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                           if (granted) {
                                               completion([[accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType] lastObject]);
                                           } else {
                                               NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                           }
                                       }];
}

- (void)updateFeed
{
    [self doFacebookAuthCompletion:^(ACAccount* account) {
        // What we want to get
        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/microsoft/feed"];
        NSDictionary* parameters = @{ };

        // The request
        SLRequest* request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                               requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                         URL:url
                                                  parameters:parameters];
        [request setAccount:account];

        // Send it
        [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
            } else {
                NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
                NSLog(@"Response Data: %@", dataString);
            }
        }];
    }];
}
```

I have even tried using the app token referenced at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/ that is only safe to use server-side, but still didn't get anywhere. This code:

```
- (void)doFacebookAuthCompletion:(void (^)(ACAccount* account))completion
{
    ACAccountStore* accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType* accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    ACAccount* account = [[ACAccount alloc] initWithAccountType:accountType];
    account.credential = [[ACAccountCredential alloc] initWithOAuthToken:@"<app-token>" tokenSecret:@"<app-secret>"];
    completion(account);
}
```

Gives the following output:

```
Response Data: {"error":{"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":104}}
```

While the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=microsoft%2Ffeed) works just fine when given the same `<app-token>` (it doesn't ask for the secret like `- initWithOAuthToken:tokenSecret:` does).

Even if this approach worked, it would not be safe to release.

I'm stuck now. Help, please?

Answer (score 2):

I can't give a complete answer because I've never used iOS, but on the Facebook side of things, the Graph API won't let you obtain anything without *some* kind of token. Secure or not, the only way to do that is to use your app id and secret to generate a token which can then be used. You can get one using, for example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
grant_type=client_credentials
```

Comment: I tried this and it works in the API Explorer, but it doesn't work on the device. The documentation specifically says that the app token should not be used in native apps, but even with the app type set to web it didn't work...

Comment: Just testing things in your web browser - do you still get the Error 104 if you try browsing to
https://graph.facebook.com/microsoft/feed/?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN
with the token generated as above?

Comment: No, it works fine in the browser. The problem seems to be limited to iOS. Maybe there's something about the way I set the token.

Comment: @VladTataranu you can use App Access token which is mostly `AppID|AppSecret` to access the **Public data**

Comment: Hi Anvesh! The second snippet of code tries that but for some reason it doesn't work.